# How to send comma seperated values from view to controller using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application I am trying to send values from .cshtml page to controller using jquery. I have written following code on button click in jquery to retrieve selected values from multi-select drop down list.

```
var selBrand = $("#BrandId option:selected");
selBrand.each(function () {
    bradValues += ',' + $(this).val();
});
```

It shows comma separated values in a string format like ',1,2,3', as I can see it using alert dialog box. Then I am trying to send this value to a controller through a variable:

```
var Discount =
{
    DiscountType: $('#DiscountType').val(),
    DiscountOn: $('#DiscountOn').val(),
    BrandId: bradValues,

}

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Discount/Create',
            data: Discount,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: "html",
            processData: true,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Ok');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

But the problem is that when I check the controller I can see single value like "1" instead of comma separated string. In module I declare BrandId (represented by bradValues) as string.

Comment: Why not `var bradValues=[]; selBrand.each(function () {
    bradValues.push($(this).val());
});`

Comment: Not working. Same result.

Comment: Then check the network tab to see if you send what you expect and then dump the request on the server

Comment: When I check the value through alert it is showing comma separated string rightly like 1,2,3 but controller is showing only the first value.

Comment: Is there any problem in "BrandId: bradValues," line? Because comma portion is always discarded.

Comment: can you show the part of the controller that receives the value?

Comment: make `data: Discount,` to `data:JSON.Stringify(Discount),` and try

Answer (score 0):

Well It would be better if you share the controller side of code as well. however there are two things I would suggest you to check.

Use console.log(Discount.BrandId) to ensure the value indeed is in comma separated form (you mentioned in the comment that you are sure that's fine).

that leaves us to point two, in your controller, are you using `List<string>` to hold a value of this parameter or a `string`. I would suggest to make an array of BrandID here in JS Code and then post it to controller and try getting these values in `List<string>`
instead.

Comment: My controller code is rather simple: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Discount Discount)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }